# TWIG errors after upgrade to PHP 8

Tags: bootstrap-theme

We have a D9 site running on Acquia. It uses a Bootstrap based subtheme.  When we upgraded PHP from 7.4 to 8 we get this error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string - null in __TwigTemplate_0256ea2515fa880b0671f8a508ce41f69921e50f3e6fa4ddf6cb0a079db2e987->block_navbar() (line 95 of /mnt/tmp/insidescienced8ide/php_storage/twig/twig/62b4874a2f4bf_page.html.twig_cAlraWEWb4deXlEGXnzn_mlxi/MCicmo0uhbkPC0ZydVY1-_R8TO4AX5CJbKuJplq5fCM.php).
```

This is what I think is the relevant section of the TWIG template:

```
 {% if not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}
    <div class="{{ container }}">
  {% endif %}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `container` null?

Comment: Try `{% if container and not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}`